# Dynamically add PropertyChanges to a State in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Is it possible to extend or dynamically add property changes to a qml state?

For example

```
Item {
    id: myItem;
    state: "opened";

    states: [
        State {
            name: "opened";

            PropertyChanges {
                target: myItem;
                height: 100;
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "closed";

            PropertyChanges {
                target: myItem;
                height: 10;
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but later I want to be able to add any other property to the PropertyChanges, such as color, width, opacity, etc. *dynamically*.  The "result" would look something like this

```
State {
    name: "closed";

    PropertyChanges {
        target: myItem;
        height: 10;
        color: "red";
        width: 10;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I know QMLdoesn't support this feature but if you clarify what is the purpose of this action I guess we will find a solution.